# Finding and deleting bad symbolic links in windows

Tags: windows, ntfs

Is there any simple way to find broken ntfs symbolic links in windows and delete them? (other than manual search and destroy)

I'm in this mess because of windows home server's inability to upgrade without removing disks :/ and the files are scattered randomly on a bunch of disks (but the structure is intact and mirrored on all disks)

Comment: Retagged.  Perhaps you'll get more responses for this on http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Junction Link Magic](http://www.rekenwonder.com/linkmagic.htm) should find and delete bad symbolic links:

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [SageLinks](https://github.com/raspopov/SageLinks/releases) utility (it's open source), it shows and test NTFS junctions, symbolic links and shortcuts.

Comment: You must disclose your affiliation in your answers http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion

Comment: @Nikolay Raspopov,
I'm unable to install your application. I get the "Unable to import" some .dll file in the temp directory.  Also, my anti-virus says that it has a trojan in it.

Comment: @Liars_Paradox, VirusTotal reports: 
[SageLinks 32-bit](https://www.virustotal.com/ru/file/1ea1b7432eee41b4df9deea29d31d30d52b2abbd221468cb5c372741cd959383/analysis/1489634934/), 
[SageLinks 64-bit](https://www.virustotal.com/ru/file/5ddb93b1b9aefc10aa75d27ef3a923d8128e4b8fdd1479f7df9f397b98853866/analysis/1489634908/). 
SageLinks uses [Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53840), setup downloads and install it automatically if missing, but you can download it yourself directly from Microsoft.

Comment: Ah, Microsoft updated redistributables to version "14.0.24215" and deleted (!) old one (setup want version "14.0.24210"). I'll update SageLinks soon. Thank you!